# Chinese Checkers Puzzle: Pawns Movement

Tags: combinatorics, convex-optimization, puzzle

I have a question how to solve the following problem.

First, we have a chess board and two pawns located at $a1$ and $a2$. Our goal is to move them to the location $h7$ and $h8$. The rules for a pawn movement are the following:

1. We can move our pawn regularly just by moving it by one unit up, down, left, or right.
2. The pawn can jump over another pawn. If there is some space before another pawn, it will jump symmetrically skipping the equal number of empty squares after it lands. For example, if the pawn are located at a1 and a4, then after the jump they will located at a4 and a7.

Question: What is the minimum number of moves we need to perform to move our pawns from the initial to the final destination ?

Comment: Where did you get this puzzle?

Comment: I came up with it while I was playing Chinese checkers with friends.

Comment: Easy to find a particular  solution in 14 moves by hand (if I understand well the problem). But how to prove it is optimal or not?

Comment: @Damien, yeah, I found one with 13 moves.

Comment: @MaximZubkov Congratulations. I hope you will provide the optimal solution at the end, if no answer provides it.

Comment: Can the pawns jump if they are on different columns _and_ rows

Comment: for example one is one a1 and the other is on b2, can the pawn jump and reach c3 according to your rules?

Comment: @AdilMohammed If slant jumps are possible then 8 moves will suffice: a2-b2 to set the pair diagonally, then 6 'unit' jumps along the diagonal from position (a1,b2) to (g7,h8) and the last step g7-g8.

Comment: Given that diagonal/slant moves and jumps are not allowed, I wonder if one can prove a Lemma saying that an optimal solution exists where either most(?) vertical moves/jumps, or most(?) horizontal moves/jumps, are consecutive. (My 13-move solution has this property.) That way the problem can be "decomposed" and the optimality search might be easier if done by hand.

Comment: @antkam I'm not quite sure I understand. IMHO the same destination point can be reached with sequence RRUU (right, right, up, up)  or with RUUR or RURU. Why the first one is 'optimal'?

Comment: @CiaPan - Sorry for being unclear.  There can definitely be many (equally-)optimal sequences, many of which are not "decomposable" (in some TBD sense), but if we can prove that THERE EXISTS an optimal sequence which is "decomposable", then we can restrict the analysis / manual search to only decomposable sequences, i.e. just find the optimal among decomposable sequences, which might make the problem easier.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to solve since there are less than 64x64 positions. Let A(n) be the set of positions that can be reached from the start position in n moves, and B(m) the set of positions that can reach the end position in m moves. Calculate A(1), B(1), A(2), B(2) etc. until
you find A(n) and B(m) with a common element, then the solution is n+m.

Comment: So, according to this solution, I can just write a program that will give me the answer. This is a brute force approach, and I wonder if there is a faster way to find a lower bound.